# Is it possible to pass data from routeProvider resolve to a factory/service?

Tags: angularjs

In my route provider I have a resolve object that returns some data from a JSON file. I can pass it without any problems to my controller but there is an error (unknown provider) when I try to pass it to my factory or service. Is there a workaround for this?

Route Provider:

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  (...)
      resolve: {
          'someData': function($http) {
              (...)
              return response.data;
          }
      }
  });
}])
```

Factory:

```
.factory('generateAvatarsFactory', ['someData', function(someData) {
(...)
// throws an unknown provider error
```

Controller:

```
.controller('SomeName', ['someData', function(someData) {
(...)
// works fine
```

Comment: Pass it as parameter of the method of your service. A service is a singleton. It can't depend on some data resolved every time you navigate to a route.

Answer (score 1):

You should set that in the service by a method like this instead of passing it to the service an input, since services are singleton:

```
.factory('generateAvatarsFactory', ['someData', function(someData) {
    this.data = {};

    this.setValue = function(value) {
       this.data = value;
    }
}]);
```

And then in your routeProvider:

```
resolve: {
  'someData': function($http) {
      (...)
      generateAvatarsFactory.setValue(response.data);
      return response.data;
  }
}
```